# Shell commands with Ansible

Tags: cron, ansible

I would like to use Ansible in order to execute several commands. In my case, I would like to create a file system. Here my code:

```
- name: Create file system
   raw: |
   mkdir -p {{ out }} {{ scripts }} {{ sql }}
   chown -R postgres:postgres {{ root_dir }}
   lvcreate -n lv_test -L 5G data_vg
   mkfs.ext4 {{ fs }}
   mount {{ fs }} {{ home }}
   when: (target_app  == "app")
```

I want to do all these actions by using the `root` user. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `shell` module similar to this:

```
- name: set a fact
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: add users
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    shell: |
        mkdir -p /tmp/blah/moreblah;
        chown -R root:root /tmp/blah/moreblah
```

That being said there are modules like `file` that can do some of the lifting for you. E.g.

```
# create a directory if it doesn't exist
- file:
    path: /etc/some_directory
    state: directory
    group: root
    owner: root
    mode: 0755
    recurse: yes
```

In general, if you're using shell to perform everyday UNIX commands you're probably doing it wrong.

**References**

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html

Comment: Thank you for your response, I still have a question concerning the `shell ` module. Can you specify a user in order to do the shell commands ? I need to be root to do this.

Comment: I adapted my answer, adding the `become_user: root` . That should do what you're looking for.